# Custom settings in MSBuild for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, properties, jenkins, msbuild, windows-phone

I have a Jenkins server that executes MSBuild for me.
There's a whole bunch of builds that need to be done, they all use the same solution file but for every build some custom settings need to change.

The app needs to be able to read these settings.

For example if I'd build like this:

```
 msbuild MyProject.sln /p:MyVar=SomeValue
```

Then when the app launches, it should be able to retrieve what the value is of MyVar.
For example, the app should be able to show a messagebox when it starts with the title 'SomeValue'.

I know I can define properties as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171481.aspx) by Microsoft, but I can't figure out how to read those properties when the app starts.
Or maybe I'm just looking at a completely wrong way of doing it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You would need msbuild to create a text file with the value inside of it. For that you can use the `TemplateFile` task of the `MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Target` in your msbuild file.

`CreateAppVarFile.targets` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(SolutionDir)\.build</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />

  <Target Name="CreateAppVarFile">
    <ItemGroup>
      <TemplateContext Include="MyVar">
        <ReplacementValue>$(MyVar)</ReplacementValue>
      </TemplateContext>
    </ItemGroup>
    <TemplateFile Template="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)appvar.txt" OutputFilename="$(ProjectDir)appvar.txt" Tokens="@(TemplateContext)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

This target would then be included in your project file

```
<Import Project=".\build\CreateAppVarFile.targets" />
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" DependsOnTargets="CreateAppVarFile">
```

and your `.\build\appvar.txt` template file in the folder where your CreateAppVarFile.targets file is located can look just like this:

```
$(MyVar)
```

and be read from your app during runtime. Don't forget to include the appvar.txt in your project. It will contain:

```
SomeValue
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. I have setup up the project like you told me, but I get this error: "F:\BuildApp\BuildApp.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
(_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks(3,5): 
error MSB4068: The element <PropertyGroup> is unrecognized, or not supported in this context. 
[F:\BuildApp\BuildApp.csproj]